# Convertendo float para array de char em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, conversão-de-tipo, char, float

Recentemente fiz uma prova e havia uma questão que pedia para que um número como `123.456` fosse exibido como `321.456`. Eu pensei que a melhor solução seria converter isto para um array de `char` e logo em seguida criar um algoritmo para imprimir posição por posição, utilizando ponteiros, com o `.` e o `\0` servido como tokens de parada. Eu implementei o algoritmo, mas não sei como fazer essa conversão de um `float` para um array de `char` de forma que cada algarismo fique em uma posição.

Como eu faço para converter um `float` em um array de `char` em `C/C++`?

Também fiquei curioso em saber como faço para fazer isto com outros tipos. `int` para `char`, `byte` para `char` e fazer o processo contrário também (`char` para `float`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Apesar das outras respostas solucionarem o problema, coloquei esta questão na prova justamente para forçar os acadêmicos de engenharia a pensarem em uma solução matemática. Isto é mais simples, natural e eficiente do que chamar funções para manipular *strings*.**

Perceba que o que este exercício solicitava na verdade, era trocar os dígitos da unidade e da centena do número. Bem, isto pode ser realizado da seguinte maneira:

```
float num = 123.456f;
int parte_inteira = num;
float parte_decimal = num - parte_inteira;

int digito_centena = parte_inteira / 100;
int digito_dezena = parte_inteira % 100 / 10;
int digito_unidade = parte_inteira % 10;

float num_invertido = (digito_unidade*100) + (digito_dezena*10) + digito_centena + parte_decimal;
printf("%0.3f\n", num_invertido);
```

Acredito que o código acima é bastante educativo e por isso não entrarei em mais detalhes.

É claro, essas operações poderiam ser realizadas na mesma linha com a ajuda de conversões explícitas de tipos de dados (*cast*), economizando declarações de variáveis:

```
float num_invertido = (((int)num % 10) * 100) +
                      (((int)num % 100 / 10) * 10) +
                       ((int)num / 100) +
                       (num - (int)num);
printf("%0.3f\n", num_invertido);
```

Comment: Obrigado. Não havia pensando nesta solução. Bastante interessante. =)

Comment: My pleasure! Cuidado quem você xinga por aqui, hehe. ;)

Comment: Só pra pegar no seu pé: estava claro no enunciado que o objetivo era trocar os dois dígitos, e que isso deveria ser efetuado por operações matemáticas? E qual seria a utilidade prática de inverter a posição da centena e da unidade? Nevertheless, +1 no comentário acima pelo bom-humor. Não voto na resposta pois a linguagem não é a minha praia (embora entenda a solução).

Comment: @bfavaretto Este era apenas um item numa questão mais elaborada, e os alunos tinham liberdade total para solucionar este probleminha da maneira que fosse mais conveniente para eles. O propósito desta tarefa era **exercitar o raciocínio lógico e aprimorar a percepção**: havia uma outra questão na prova que respondia parcialmente este desafio. De qualquer maneira, esta técnica aritmética de extrair dígitos específicos de um número é muito utilizada no desenvolvimento de sistemas embarcados, especialmente quando se trabalha com streams de dados em tempo real, como é o caso de transmissões DTV.

Answer (score 9):

Em `C`, você pode fazer:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    float valor = 123.456;
    char convertido[16];
    sprintf(convertido, "%.3f", valor);

    printf("A float convertido = %s", convertido);

    return 0;
}
```

Detalhe para o `%.3f`, indicando 3 casas decimais. Usando apenas `%f` pode ocorrer conversões além do que você quer tipo `123.45600001` no seu `char[]`;

O `sprinf` pode ser utilizado para outros tipos também (`int`, `char`), você só tem que mudar o parâmetro `%f` para o que você quer.

---

Em C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){

    float valor = 123.456;
    std::string resultado = std::to_string(valor);
    const char* convertido = resultado.c_str();

    std::cout << "O float convertido = " << convertido << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Também serve para `int`, `char` e etc.

---

Em versões mais antigos de C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T a_value)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << a_value;
    return out.str();
}

int main(){

    float valor = 123.456;

    std::string resultado = to_string(valor);
    const char* convertido = resultado.c_str();
    std::cout << "O float convertido = " << convertido << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excelente resposta. 

Você saberia me dizer como é feita a implementação da função sprintf? Eu tentei encontrar na internet mas não achei.

Comment: A implementação é bem grande. Você pode ver a versão do gcc se baixar a `glibc` e procurar em `stdio-common`. Pesquise sobre análise lexica, também tem a ver.

Comment: Não precisa passar explicitamente o argumento template para o `to_string` (último exemplo).

Answer (score 5):

Em C puro basta você usar a função `sprintf` que trabalha da mesma maneira que o `printf` mas invés de mandar a saída para o console você pode salvá-la em uma variável.

Em `C`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WORD_LENGTH 64

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float value = 123.456F;
    char str[WORD_LENGTH];

    sprintf(str, "%.3f", value);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Em `C++` você tem a liberdade de usar a mesma solução que no `C`, mas ele também possui uma saída própria.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float value = 123.456F;
    stringstream stream;
    string output;

    stream << value;

    output = stream.str();

    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Já em `C++11` a versão mais recente, você pode usar simplesmente.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float value = 123.456F;
    string output = std::to_string(value);

    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma possível solução seria:

```
float flt = 123.456;
char mybuff1[50];
sprintf (mybuff1, "%f", flt);
char *c [] = {mybuff1};
```

Tem um post explicando melhor no stackoverflow.com: [how can i assign float value to char* c[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11841863/edit) Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obs: Se não funcionar me avisa.

Comment: Melhor é usar `snprintf` para evitar estouro de buffer.